# excel SVERWEIS displays #NV

Tags: excel

hope you can help me :-)

My table looks like this:

```
A             B             C                D
23940823   Larissa       Horst         =VLOOKUP(C1;A1:B2000;1;FALSE)
23940824   Horst         Leon          =VLOOKUP(C2;A1:B2000;1;FALSE)
23940825   Fred          Kim           =VLOOKUP(C3;A1:B2000;1;FALSE)
23940826   Horst         Peter         =VLOOKUP(C4;A1:B2000;1;FALSE)
```

I would like to get the number from the specific A, if the Value of C is in B. So for "Horst" it should be "23940824"in this case, but it only displays "#NV".. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `SVERWEIS` search the first column and goes to right. You need here `INDEX` instead:

`=INDEX(A:A;C1)` 'where C1 is your search string

See also MS-docu: https://support.office.com/de-de/article/INDEX-Funktion-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd

**Update**

First check if the value of cell C is in column B. If so it displays the  value of cell A he is finding:

[image]

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C1;B:B;0));"Not in Column B";INDEX(A:A;MATCH(C1;C:C;0)))` 'for D1

Remember that the key words could be different if you use no english excel version (like english = IF, german = WENN)

Comment: It actually it does not work. May I do sth wrong? Sorry my Excel skills arent the best.

What I am trying to do is, to get the value of A when C exists in B

Comment: Oh Im sorry. I forgot to translate the keywords!
There is still a problem:
For example D1 should bee 23940826 but in your Version its 23940824 (the wrong row). What has to be changed?
Thanks for your big help!! :-)

Comment: actual it looks only if the search string (C1) is in column B and if so it shows the value of A (in this case A1). If you want to show something different then you need a additionally criteria